# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Search> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am very new to React and TypeScript. I am developing a web page in Visual Studio 2017 where I have a search component which I would like to use in my home component. But after importing search into my home component, I get a compile time error saying:

```
Type {} is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Search> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>  
Type {} is not assignable to type Readonly<SearchForm>  
 Property 'suggestionList' is missing in type {}
```

Search Component code:

```
export class Search extends React.Component<SearchForm> { //SearchForm is a class with string and an object of another class as properties
constructor() {
    super();
}
```

Home component code:

```
   export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> 
   {
   return <div>
        < Search /> // <=Getting error at this line
   <div>
   }
```

If I remove `RouteComponentProps<{}>` from Home component, then I get an error in route.tsx file. I know, I must be doing something wrong or some silly mistake. I googled this but I am not getting any helpful answers. Can somebody tell me how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing required properties of `Search` component, the error shows `suggestion List`. You need something like:

```
<div>
  <Search suggestionList={...} />
</div>
```

(and maybe not only `suggestionList` is missing)

React.Component definition is:

```
interface Component<P = {}, S = {}>
```

where `P` defines components properties and `S` the state. You must pass to the component all requiered properties defined in `P`.

In your example, component properties type is `SearchForm`. Therefore you need to pass, at least, all required attributes of `SearchForm`.

Please refer to [Define Props and State Types](https://charleslbryant.gitbooks.io/hello-react-and-typescript/content/DefinePropsAndStateTypes.html) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: Okay. So SearchForm has two props:- a string and an object. But how do i pass these values because if i do <Search suggestionList={...} /> it still gives me error. Maybe it is a bit different in typescript??

Comment: You have to replace `{...}` with the list or the variable that contains the list:  `<Search suggestionList={myList} />`. And so with all required properties you have defined.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to create functional component you can use generics in order to get rid of this error. Consider this example.

```
interface SearchProps {
  suggestionList: any
}

export const Search: React.FC<SearchProps> = ({suggestionList}): JSX.Element => {
   return <div>...</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Tobías said, you are missing the required properties of Search component.

Giving all props a value will fix it:

```
<Search prop1={'string'} prop2={obj} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to spread the props object. to elaborate:

i have this component

```js
const Component: FunctionComponent<ComponentProps> =
    (props) => {
//component code
}
```

and here where it is invoked; where we have the props object and the component

```js
  const componentProps: ComponentProps= {
        //properties
title:'title 1',
//etc...
    }
<Component/>
```

to assign the props object as props to the component
you should spread the object in the component

```js
<Component {...componentProps} />
```